# Cannot retrieve array values in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have got a quick noob question: I am trying to retrieve the values of an array and printing them to an html element with jQuery "on Click". However, I cannot seem to retrieve the array elements. For each clicked item it should get the array element at index `i` , so `#item-0` should get the value of `"red"`, etc.

The console logs `undefined`.

```js
var descriptions = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple", "white", "black"];

for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
  $("#item-" + i).on("click", function() {
    var currentDescr = descriptions[i];
    console.log(currentDescr);

    $("#footer-text").html(currentDescr);
  });
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `clossure`  or `let`(`let i = 0;`)

Comment: What do you mean "the console logs `undefined`"? I can't see any `console.log` statements in your code.

Comment: Any more specific? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because when you are clicking the button the value of `i` would be `descriptions.length` (at that point loop is breaking) since there is no value at that index it would be `undefined`.

You can solve this by using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` which provide block level scope.

```
var descriptions = ["red","blue","green","purple","white","black"];


for (let i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
  $("#item-"+i).on("click", function(){
    var currentDescr = descriptions[i];
    console.log(currentDescr);
    $("#footer-text").html(currentDescr);
  });
};
```

---

or use a [closure function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and pass `i` as an argument.

```
var descriptions = ["red","blue","green","purple","white","black"];


for (let i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
  (function(index){
    $("#item-" + index).on("click", function(){
      var currentDescr = descriptions[index];
      console.log(currentDescr);
      $("#footer-text").html(currentDescr);
    });
  })(i);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop is finishing before the events fire, leading to an incorrect value of `i`... Try this:

```
var descriptions = ["red","blue","green","purple","white","black"];


for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {

    (function(i){
        $("#item-"+i).on("click", function(){

           var currentDescr = descriptions[i];
           console.log(currentDescr);
           $("#footer-text").html(currentDescr);

       });
    }(i));
};
```

Comment: I made a demo and facing same issue but your solution helped. https://jsfiddle.net/ohzcvqvk/